# Who was the Halach Uinik of Can Pech?

Tags: colonial-america, maya

Who was the ruler ([Halach Uinik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halach_Uinik)) of the pre-conquest [Mayan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_civilization#Postclassic_period_(c._950%E2%80%931539_AD)) state ([Kuchkabal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuchkabal)) of [Can Pech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Can_Pech) around the beginning of the 16th century? If not the individual, the dynasty?

Comment: Thank you for the links. I've further edited to use the English terms for the Mayan words, to make this question understandable to most without clicking the links.